# Playing back recorded PCM audio data in the browser

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, mediarecorder, audiocontext

I'm trying to get audio data from the microphone in a raw PCM format and I'm trying to play back audio data recorded in a raw PCM format using JavaScript in the browser.

For that purpose I wrote two simple classes:

```
AudioRecorder.startRecording()
AudioRecorder.stopRecording(): returns the recorded audio data as a PCM BufferArray

AudioPlayer.play(pcmAudioDataBufferArray)
AudioPlayer.stop()
```

The `AudioRecorder` class seems to work just fine, but my `AudioRecorder.play()` method has an issue:

```
  async play(pcmAudioDataBufferArray) {
    if (this.playing) {
      throw new Error("Audio is already playing!");
    }

    if (!pcmAudioDataBufferArray) {
      throw new Error("No audio data provided!");
    }

    this.playing = true;
    const audioBuffer = await this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(pcmAudioDataBufferArray);
    const source = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(this.audioContext.destination);

    const endedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      source.addEventListener("ended", resolve, { once: true });
      source.addEventListener('error', reject, { once: true });
    });

    source.start();

    await endedPromise;
    this.playing = false;
  }
```

It always throws:

```
Error: EncodingError: The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.
```

I tested this in Firefox which by default seems to be recording the data in ogg/opus format as a blob, which I then convert into a PCM BufferArray using this code:

```
  async audioBlobToPcmBuffer(blob) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    const arrayBuffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fileReader.onload = () => resolve(fileReader.result);
      fileReader.onerror = reject;
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
    const audioCtx = new AudioContext({ sampleRate: this.sampleRate });
    const audioBuffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
    const pcmBuffer = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).buffer;
    return pcmBuffer;
  }
```

Any ideas, what I might be doing wrong?

Here is my full code in case anyone is interested: https://codepen.io/T-vK/pen/MWqPKGd?editors=1010

The reason for wanting to use PCM rather than the default browser formats is that my goal is to send the audio to a server which only understands raw PCM formats.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already decoded the audio data within the `audioBlobToPcmBuffer()` function you don't have to do it again when playing it back. You can just pretend the data is in the right format and use the `ArrayBuffer` to back an `AudioBuffer`.

It should work if you replace the relevant part of the `play()` function with the following snippet.

```js
async play(pcmAudioDataBufferArray) {
  // ...
  // const audioBuffer = await this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(pcmAudioDataBufferArray);
  this.playing = true;
  const audioBuffer = new AudioBuffer({
    length: pcmAudioDataBufferArray.byteLength / 4,
    sampleRate: this.audioContext.sampleRate
  });

  audioBuffer.copyToChannel(new Float32Array(pcmAudioDataBufferArray), 0);

  const source = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
  // ...
}
```

The downside of your approach is that you record in a lossy format at first before decoding the data back into PCM data. The other problem is that you potentially resample the audio if the `AudioContext` runs on a different `sampleRate` as the recording.

You could avoid all that by recording PCM data directly. I'm the author of [extendable-media-recorder](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder) and do of course recommend using it. But it's worth mentioning that it's not the only tool that can record audio as PCM.